# Read system TMP dir in R

Tags: r, cross-platform, cran

What is a cross-platform method to find the OS temporary directory from within R? I currently use:

```
dirname(tempdir())
```

Which did the job both on Ubuntu and Windows from within an interactive R session. However, then it failed when called from inside RApache. In RApache the value of `tempdir()` is always `/tmp`, so `dirname(tempdir())` results in `/`, which is obviously wrong. I also tried:

```
Sys.getenv("TMP")
Sys.getenv("TEMP")
Sys.getenv("TMPDIR")
```

as suggested by `?"environment variables"` but none of these were set in Ubuntu. It also doesn't seem to be set in any of the files in `/etc/R/*` so I don't quite understand how R detects this value.

Comment: Why `tempdir()` always return `/tmp` is puzzling. Do you have write access to that dir?

Comment: I think rApache sets the C level global `R_TempDir` to implement some caching. See https://github.com/jeffreyhorner/rapache

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The environment variables "TMPDIR", "TMP", and "TEMP" can be used to modify the value returned by `tempdir()` if the C variable `R_TempDir` isn't set (although I'm not sure how that is done).  If you want a cross-platform function that will return the path of a reasonable tmp directory, and aren't interested in the value of `R_TempDir`, you could use something like this:

```
gettmpdir <- function() {
  tm <- Sys.getenv(c('TMPDIR', 'TMP', 'TEMP'))
  d <- which(file.info(tm)$isdir & file.access(tm, 2) == 0)
  if (length(d) > 0)
    tm[[d[1]]]
  else if (.Platform$OS.type == 'windows')
    Sys.getenv('R_USER')
  else
    '/tmp'
}
```

This is based on the function `InitTempDir` in the file src/main/sysutils.c from the R source distribution, translated from C to R.